# export data in excel from mysql in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, excel, codeigniter

I am exporting data from mysql to excel in codeigniter it's working fine on localhost
but it's not working on server .on server it prints only array like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 135
            [type] => 3
            [product_service] => 
            [email] => bewcontrols@gmail.com
            [first_name] => gurwinder sigh
            [last_name] => 
            [company_name] => 
            [country] => 
            [state] => 
            [city] => 
            [phone_number] => 91-011-09971587701
            [mobile] => 09971587701
            [fax_number] => 
            [address] => f-127 mayapuri indl area phase2 new delhi
            [zipcode] => 
            [message] => Subject: Fwd to purchase/ maint. for repairing of SOLENOID VALVE and PNEUMATIC cylinders ,DELHI,BHUPINDER ENGG.

Dear Sir,

I'd like to take this opportunity to introduce BEW Pneumatic
Controls,Delhi, to you.

We manufacture Heavy Duty Solenoid Valves in   Spool construction
using all-Aluminium fittings.While most manufacturers use plastic
fittings,plastic cages, we at BEW pioneered Aluminium fittings and
have incorporated them across our product line.

Please find attached our latest product catalogue for your perusal and
we look forward to hearing from you soon.

Best Regards,

Gurwinder Singh
Mobile-09811019362,
     and 09971587701

        [status] => 1
        [reply_status] => N
        [receive_date] => 2014-11-16 18:22:06
        [order_quantity] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 134
        [type] => 3
        [product_service] => 
        [email] => mohamed@gmail.com
        [first_name] => mohamed
        [last_name] => 
        [company_name] => 
        [country] => 
        [state] => 0
        [city] => 
        [phone_number] => 
        [mobile] => 9944556611
        [fax_number] => 
        [address] => 
        [zipcode] => 
        [message] => jhkhjh
        [status] => 1
        [reply_status] => N
        [receive_date] => 2014-11-11 15:42:47
        [order_quantity] => 20
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
//fputcsv($output, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));

// fetch the data
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db("database");
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT something, something, something FROM table');

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok its simple in CI
Just download csv library
then

```
 $this->db->select('*')->from('yourtabl')->where(array('your_conditions')); 
 $query = $this->db->get();
$this->load->helper('csv');
   query_to_csv($query, TRUE, 'yourfilename.csv');
```

and bingo